# React - How can i close all other tooltips?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a tooltip component provided to me from work which all works great, so I have made a Tooltip Wrapper to fulfil extra requirements.

The issue is i want to close all other instances of the tooltip when i tap on another. I have already added a click event listener for window so any instances of the tooltip are closed whenever i click else ware. The issue i'm having is that this `handleWindowClick` event doesn't fire when i click on another tooltip and as a result i am able to open multiple tooltips at once. When the requirement is that, whenever a tooltip is opened, the other closes so there is only ever one tooltip open at once.

```
import { Tooltip } from "Tooltip";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TooltipWrapper extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.handleWindowClick = this.handleWindowClick.bind(this);
        this.toggleTooltip = this.toggleTooltip.bind(this);
        this.onTooltipClosed = this.onTooltipClosed.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    toggleTooltip() {
        this.setState({
            show: !this.state.show
        });
    }

    handleWindowClick(event) {
        this.setState({
            show: false
        });
    }

    onTooltipClosed() {
        this.setState({
            show: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Tooltip
                open={this.state.show}
                tip={this.props.tip}
                position="bottom"
                closeButton="visible"
                onClose={this.onTooltipClosed}
            >
                <div onClick={this.toggleTooltip}>{this.props.children}</div>
            </Tooltip>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `event.stopPropagation();` in your window event and where else are you calling it? I expect something is preventing the event from propagating to the window object.

Comment: I have removed the `event.stopPropagation()` and the issue persists. All tooltips are closed as expected when i click anywhere in the window. Except when I click on another tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding click listener to body may help you, please try this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', this.onClickBody);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked and what i was looking for.

Comment: Any info on why the document.body event listener worked and the other didnt

Comment: windows is the parrent of every object in browser. u can use window.document or just document.
document is the main object of rendered html. 
and since u want to add event to what is rendered u have to use document

Comment: While this might work the reasoning it not true, all click events will reach the window unless they are blocked. Something listening on document body is blocking the click from bubbling, see console of http://jsfiddle.net/Lu5tbevh/

Comment: I think the reason behind this not working is the bubbling and capturing concept of javascript. currently you are using bubbling (by default) concept as per which first child element event id fired and then ancestor's(in this case window). so you click on tooltip it opens and then window event is fired which closes all the tooltip.

Comment: I guess my question would be then. With either of these solutions Im having an issue where the `document.body` event listener is firing before my `toggleTooltip` onClick handler. This is preventing me from closing my tooltips as the `handleWindowClick` method is setting my show state then toggleTooltip has the wrong state